# Why cannot I modify collection through up bounded reference but can through its iterator?

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard, type-erasure

```
    List<? extends Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>(){
        {addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));}
    };
    ListIterator  listIterator = list1.listIterator();
    listIterator.next();
    listIterator.set(999);
    System.out.println(list1);
```

this code works and outs

```
[999, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But if I write so:

```
        List<? extends Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>(){
            {addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));}
        };
        list1.set(0,999);
```

I see

```
java: method set in interface java.util.List<E> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Number
  found: int,int
  reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Number by method invocation conversion
```

Plese clarify this behaviour.

**P.S.**
This question was arisen after watching code from

`Collections.reverse` method

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) {
        int size = list.size();
        if (size < REVERSE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
            for (int i=0, mid=size>>1, j=size-1; i<mid; i++, j--)
                swap(list, i, j);
        } else {
            ListIterator fwd = list.listIterator();
            ListIterator rev = list.listIterator(size);
            for (int i=0, mid=list.size()>>1; i<mid; i++) {
                Object tmp = fwd.next();
                fwd.set(rev.previous());
                rev.set(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your iterator is a raw type; it should be `ListIterator<? extends Number>` (and your IDE should warn you of this).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth therefore in JDK uses mixin raw type and Generic ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What does this have to do with mixins?

Comment: I am about using raw types and generic types together

Comment: I have heard that it is a bad style

Comment: Yes, it is a bad style.  So you shouldn't do it!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth In my brain I have two prerequisities: 1. JDK was written by very clever men and 2.it is a bad style.... I am confused

Comment: please read **Collections#reverse** method

Comment: Large chunks of the Java Collections were written before generics existed.

Comment: But this method signature contains generic wild card. Was this code refactored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code example is complete, it is because you have dropped the generic information from your ListIterator definition. If you were to change it to include the generic info it would return a similar compilation error:

```
List<? extends Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>(){
    {addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));}
};
ListIterator<? extends Number>  listIterator = list1.listIterator();
listIterator.next();
listIterator.set(999);
System.out.println(list1);
```

Similarly, if you stripped the generic definition from your list you could add item directly without issue:

```
    List<? extends Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>(){
        {addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));}
    };
    List list2 = list1;
    list2.set(0,999);
```

This all comes down the fact that generics are really just syntactical sugar that aid in compilation, but are "erased" at runtime.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html